# react-native-view-shot: NativeModules.RNViewShot is undefined. Make sure the library is linked on the native side

Tags: react-native, screenshot, screen-capture, react-android, react-native-view-shot

I'm trying to capture View in react native but got the **NativeModules.RNViewShot is undefined** error.

Things I've tried

- Manual Linking
- Restart/rebuild project
- Deleted node modules
- Downgrade package version

If there is any other alternative of **react-native-view-shot** please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided enough information to provide you with a solution. The NativeModules undefined error comes when the project has not been linked properly. Which version of react-native and the package are you using? Can you see the react-native-view-shot build.gradle file in the Android Studio. That is a good way to know that the project has been linked properly.

Comment: I meant to say can you set the build.gradle in Android Studio project explorer.